# Angular - divide td tag into separate columns dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, html-table

I´m trying to divide dynamically the  table element to it´s own separate columns. My desired output looks like this: [image]

Value for name and surname is always 1, but values for subjects and grade are dynamic (there can be 2 columns or more).

This is my data:

```
data = [
    {
      student: 'Student 1',
      name: 'Alex',
      surname: 'Smith',
      subjects: ['Math','Geometry'],
      grade: ['A','B'],
    },
    {
      student: 'Student 2',
      name: 'Michael',
      surname: 'Laurent',
      subjects: ['Math','Geometry'],
      grade: ['B','C'],
    },
    {
      student: 'Student 3',
      name: 'Sophie',
      surname: 'Miller',
      subjects: ['Math','Geometry','English'],
      grade: ['A','A','B'],
    },
  ];
```

HTML:

```
<table>
  <thead>
     <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th *ngFor="let column of data">{{ column.student }}</th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr *ngFor="let row of rows">
         <th>{{ row.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + row.slice(1) }}</th>
         <td *ngFor="let item of data">{{ item[row] }}</td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is a stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pzgohu
Does anybody know what could be solution? I tried to put span inside td tag and loop through the .length, but it works wrong when I put length on string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use condition based on row value or you can use typeof to check if it is a string or array https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th *ngFor="let column of data">{{ column.student }}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of rows">
      <th>{{ row.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + row.slice(1) }}</th>
      <td *ngFor="let item of data">
        <span *ngIf="row !== 'subjects' && row !== 'grade'">
          {{ item[row] }}
        </span>

        <table *ngIf="row === 'subjects' || row === 'grade'">
          <tr>
            <td *ngFor="let subItem of item[row]">
              {{ subItem }}
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```